# 'donne incinte' o 'donne incinta'?

Tags: plural

In un discorso sono rimasto perplesso sul se usare 'incinta' o 'incinte'.

a) Sarà per questo che le donne *incinta* non avranno più diritto a una serie di esami?

b) Sarà per questo che le donne *incinte* non avranno più diritto a una serie di esami?

La domanda è: È corretta la a) o la b)? e perché?

Answer (score 7):

È corretta la b in quanto:

> - L'aggettivo in italiano si declina come il sostantivo. *Donne*, sostantivo femminile plurale, per cui *incinte* aggettivo femminile plurale.

PS: in questo caso la declinazione al maschile non esiste.

Comment: Aiuta ricordare il possibile etimo di “incinta”, che deriva (forse) dal latino *incincta*, cioè “non cinta”, perché le donne in attesa non portano la cintura.

Answer (score 2):

Si dice, ovviamente, donne **incinte.** Incinta è un aggettivo e come tutti gli aggettivi si declina. Dire "incinta" al plurale è sbagliato proprio come lo sarebbero *donne bella, *donne sposata o *donne emancipata. Il motivo per cui molti fanno questo errore è che considerano "incinta" come se avesse in qualche modo a che fare con il sostantivo "cinta" e quindi lo trattano come se fosse una inesistente locuzione avverbiale *in cinta.

Answer (score -5):

The correct answer is B) because `donne` is the plural of donna, so if the noun is plural, the verb will also have to be plural. The plural will be `incinte`. If it is not plural then it would mean "The women **is** pregnant". That does not make sense, because it is suppose to be "The Women **are** pregnant"

Here is a rule to know if the noun is singular or plural:

If the noun ends with `a` it is singular, but is ends with `e` it is plural.

Comment: There are lots of nouns ending in "e" that are singular.

Comment: Sure, then there are *quite a lot* of such exceptions, if you still want to call them so.

Comment: They are not exceptions, Tia, they derive from a different Latin declension.